# ios NSAttributedString firstLineHeadIndent bug

Tags: nsattributedstring

I try to use FirstLineHeadIndent,but when i use,  The string will be truncated.

```
NSString *string = @"hello，i am aaa，123456 my name is";
UIFont *textFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
self.textView = [UILabel new];
_textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:_textView];
_textView.numberOfLines = 0;

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.4;
[paragraphStyle setLineSpacing:4];
[paragraphStyle setFirstLineHeadIndent:30];
[paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentJustified];
[paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle,NSFontAttributeName:textFont,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor darkGrayColor]}];
[_textView setAttributedText:string];
```

The results of the intercept is  hello，i am aaa，123456 my.

about the first line retract, am i wrong? thanks！

Comment: What's the frame of `self.textView`? Note that textView is quite bad for a `UILabel` var name, since it would suggests that's a `UITextView`.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *textView;

Comment: but,when i change the property name, the problems still exist, you can run the code

Comment: The property name is not the issue, it's just not a recommended name as it misleading for review. What's the frame of it?

Comment: _textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 640);
Where will be a problem？

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Could you give a screenshot of your UILabel when rendered?

Comment: sorry, I want to show the screenshot, but My reputation is not enough. Can I have other ways to give you a screenshot?